# How many SDF-#'s are there?

Tags: robotech

From my understanding, there are three SDFs:

- The SDF-1 which was the major focus of the first season.
- The SDF-3 which is the flagship of the Robotech Expeditionary Force (REF), where Rick Hunter is.
- The SDF-2 I wasn't too sure about, as at first I thought it was a separate ship built, but it was apparently destroyed with the SDF-1 in the final episode of the first season. (Not entirely sure if it's a separate ship or the repaired SDF-1.)

However, in Episode 78 ("Ghost Town"), the communications from the REF were coming from the SDF-4, so I'm wondering: How many SDF-#'s are there, and are they all the same as the SDF-1 (minus the aircraft carriers which were just a patch job)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Robotech Wikia](http://robotech.wikia.com/wiki/SDF) has a list for SDF-1, SDF-2, SDF-3, SDF-4 and SDF-7. It includes a listing for SDF-M, but I don't think that was in the TV series (it's mentioned in the Robotech comics). Wikipedia also has a list of [Robotech vehicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Robotech_vehicles) that has a lot of detailed information of 1-4.

- **SDF-1**: Robotech TV series
- **SDF-2 Megalord**: Robotech TV series (starting from episode 26)
- **SDF-3 Pioneer**: First appeared in ["Crystal Dreams" promo](http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120820223908/robotech/images/f/f6/Incomplete_SDF3.jpg) and in the Robotech II: The Sentinels series
- **SDF-4 Izumo/Liberator**: Last episode of the original series
- **SDF-7**: Robotech II: The Sentinels novels
- **SDF-M**: Invid War: Aftermath comics

The SDF-7 was a Horizon Class T ship, so it's not like SDF-1.

Comment: Haven't watched the show, but Japanese Wikipedia identifies some other things called SDFN-1, SDFN-4, SDFN-8 as "first-generation Macross-class", whatever that means.

Comment: @senshin The Japanese Wiki for ["Robotech"](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%9C%E3%83%86%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)? I see it mentioned but only referring to the associated character from Macross.

Comment: The article for [Macross (fictional weapon)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9_(%E6%9E%B6%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%85%B5%E5%99%A8)), actually.

Comment: @senshin - I believe that's an entry for *Macross* (マクロス), the original anime that *Robotech* was spawned of. While both have the same initial story (more or less) they have vastly different continuities afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, Harmony Gold bought the rights to 3 different shows, heavily edited them and rewrote the script so that they can syndicate it in the states (which requires something like 63 episodes) and called it "Robotech". There is no SDFN nomenclature in Robotech.

Comment: @SystemDown Oh, I didn't know that they diverged. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

What is canon and what is non canon in Robotech is a mess, but basically the Robotech series, and the Robotech Shadow Chronicles and Robotech Love Live Alive movies are canon and the rest of movies (Robotech The Sentinels and Robotech the Untold Story) and novels and most comics are not

**There are 4 canon SDF that you could count as "real". There are more in novels and such but they are non canon versions.**

The canon SDFs are SDF-1 and SDF2 which appears in the canon Robotech series (well sort of, the SDF-2 is mentioned but never seen in the series) . The SDF-3 appears in the non canon Robotech The Sentinels movie so because of this it shouldnt count, but it also appears in the canon SDF-3 Shadow Chronicles movie, so you could count it as "real" because of this. The SDF-4 appears in the canon Robotech series and in the canon Robotech Shadow Chronicles movie.

Also what is canon might change over the years, the first 2 Robotech movies when they were made were meant to be canon (and they had its creator involved) but they were de-canonized later.